# Interface inheritance propagation when hiding method

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

If i have an interface

```
public interface IPeelable
{
    void PeelMe();
}
```

And the following inheritance tree:

```
public class Fruit : IPeelable
{
    public virtual void EatMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a fruit and I've been eaten");
    }

    public void PeelMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a fruit and I've been peeled");
    }
}

public class Banana : Fruit
{
    public override void EatMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a banana and I've been eaten");
    }

    public new void PeelMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a banana and I've been peeled");
    }
}
```

I have used the **new** keyword instead of  the virtual/override on purpose thus the **PeelMe** method in Banana is hiding the one in Fruit.

I have issues understanding why when I call:

```
IPeelable banana = new Banana();    
banana.PeelMe();// returns I'm a fruit and I've been peeled
```

there is an implicit upcast at run time.

**Method called based on inheritance paradigm**:

- *virtual/override on PeelMe* : Banana.PeelMe is called
- *redundant IPeelable inheritance* : Banana.PeelMe is called
- *PeelMe method hiding with new* : Fruit.PeelMe is called

Isn't a Banana supposed to be an IPeelable and call the PeelMe method in Banana every time ?
Can someone explain me what's happening behind the scene ?

Comment: please show the declration and assignment of the variable `banana`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sKpQ9z It works!

Comment: I've added the declaration, It was missing. That's the main point. Thank you Scott.

Comment: @SeanStayn, your link to donetfiddle is very useful, didn't know this online tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is because you are *hiding* the method rather than *overriding* it.  Overriding a method keeps the same signature but changes the implementation.  Hiding a method creates a *brand new* method without *any* polymorphic behavior.

Consider the following code:

```
Banana banana = new Banana();
banana.EatMe();

Fruit bananaAsFruit = banana;
bananaAsFruit.EatMe();
```

As you might expect, this prints `I'm a banana and I've been eaten` both times.  Since `EatMe` was declared with the `virtual` keyword in `Fruit` and overridden in `Banana`, .NET uses the *object type* to determine what method to call, regardless of the variable that maintains a reference to it.  No matter how the `Banana` object is stored, the same method always gets called.

Now consider a similar snippet that calls a *non-virtual* method.  What does this output?

```
Banana banana = new Banana();
banana.PeelMe();

Fruit bananaAsFruit = banana;
bananaAsFruit.PeelMe();
```

Despite the fact that both `banana` and `bananaAsFruit` contain the *same instance* of a `Banana`, the two calls yield different results!  That's because without the `virtual` keyword there is no connection between the `Fruit.PeelMe` and `Banana.PeelMe` methods - from the compiler's perspective, they may as well have completely different names.

Storing a `Banana` in an `IPeelable` reference variable can have one of two effects, depending on the relationship between the two types.

- If `Banana` inherits from `Fruit` which in turn implements `IPeelable`, there is no connection between `IPeelable.PeelMe` and `Banana.PeelMe`.  `Fruit` implements the `PeelMe` method for the `IPeelable` interface, and (from the compiler's perspective) the `Banana.PeelMe` method is completely different than `Fruit.PeelMe`.
- If `Banana` is declared to implement `IPeelable`, then `Banana.PeelMe` becomes the implementing method for the `IPeelable` interface.  A `Banana` stored in an `IPeelable` reference will print `I'm a banana`.

For the `EatMe` method, the runtime only looks at the type of the *actual object* to determine what to call - the type of reference pointing to it makes no difference!  That's what `virtual` and `override` do differently than method hiding.

Comment: I've digged into the IL code and the PeelMe method in Banana class is non virtual but has the same name 
    .method public hidebysig instance void 
            PeelMe() cil managed
    {

Comment: The call to PeelMe in the IL is : 
    callvirt   instance void Program/IPeelable::PeelMe()
Since the method PeelMe in banana is non virtual It's resolving to Fruit.PeelMe()

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question and I think the answer is interesting as well.

---

**Interpretation of your Question**

You asked:

Why is the output

> *I'm a fruit and I've been peeled*

and not

> *I'm a banana and I've been peeled*

if you call the following code

```
IPeelable banana = new Banana();    
banana.PeelMe();// returns I'm a fruit and I've been peeled
```

You have a class Fruit and a class Banana, but only Fruit implements the interface IPeelable. Because of this, IPeelable will instantiate an object of the class Fruit.

Based on this, your question is the same as:

Why is the output

> I'm a fruit and I've been peeled

if you call the following code

```
Fruit banana = new Banana();    
banana.PeelMe();// returns I'm a fruit and I've been peeled
```

With this question and with the additionally question:

> What happens behind?

I can you give the following answer.

---

**Answer**

> What happens behind?

If you call `Fruit banana = new Banana();` it will be allocated memory for banana, which contains both methods. The method PeelMe() from Fruit AND from Banana. And if the type of banana is Fruit, PeelMe() uses the reference to the PeelMe() from Fruit. If the type of banana is Banana, PeelMe() uses the reference to the PeelMe() from Banana.

---

**Test, to validate my answer**

- If you add a property (integer) to the class Banana and look at the allocated memory, this is the result:
  [image: Integer property added to the Banana class]
- If you add the same property (integer) to both classes (With virtual and override) and look at the allocated memory, this is the result:
  [image: Integer property added to both classes]

With the both images at the top, you can see, that you allocate memory for the integer variable from the property of Fruit and from the property of Banana.

If you want to test it, you can also do the following:

```
 public class Fruit : IPeelable
 {
     public int NumberOfBananas = 10;
     public virtual void EatMe()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I'm a fruit and I've been eaten");
     }

     public void PeelMe()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I'm a fruit and I've been peeled");
     }
 }

 public class Banana : Fruit
 {
     public new int NumberOfBananas = 5;
     public override void EatMe()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I'm a banana and I've been eaten");
     }

     public new void PeelMe()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I'm a banana and I've been peeled");
     }
 }

 private static void Main()
 {
     Fruit banana = new Banana();
     Console.WriteLine(banana.NumberOfBananas);          // Result: 10

     Banana realBanana = (Banana)banana;
     Console.WriteLine(realBanana.NumberOfBananas);      // Result: 5

     Fruit bananaFruit = (Fruit)realBanana;
     Console.WriteLine(bananaFruit.NumberOfBananas);      // Result: 10
}
```